# Docker commands failing to run inside bash script

Tags: shell-script, docker

I have a Dockerfile that I'm using to build a runtime environment for some bash scripts, currently it looks like this:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade

RUN apt-get install curl -y

# Install MySQL tools
RUN apt-get install default-mysql-client -y

# Install AWS CLI v2
RUN apt-get install awscli -y

# Install Docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
RUN chmod +x ./get-docker.sh
RUN ./get-docker.sh
RUN rm get-docker.sh

# Copy jobs into container
WORKDIR /

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `docker-entrypoint.sh` script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker --version
/jobs/$1/run.sh
```

Finally, the job that I'm running (the `run.sh` script that ends up being run by `docker-entrypoint.sh`) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker --version
```

The first execution of `docker --version` inside of `docker-entrypoint.sh` behaves as expected and outputs the Docker version. The second execution from `run.sh` fails to run with the following message:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

For some reason it seems like the inner script doesn't have access to the docker daemon while the outer script does.

Interestingly, if I actually run `./docker-entrypoint.sh [job-name]` locally, instead of within the Docker container, I get the expected output from BOTH executions.

Is anyone able to explain why this is occurring and help with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Docker socket isn’t automatically made available inside running containers; you need to mount it explicitly:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

(with appropriate suffixes, *e.g.* `:z` if SELinux is enabled).

`docker --version` works without the socket because it doesn’t *need* the Docker socket; it returns the tool’s version without contacting the daemon when `/var/run/docker.sock` doesn’t exist. The scripts in the container must be running some other `docker` command.

Comment: Both scripts are being run inside the same container - the first script (docker-entrypoint.sh) is able to use docker just fine, the second script (run.sh - executed as part of the first script) cannot use docker.

Comment: `docker --version` doesn’t need the Docker socket.

Comment: And yet, it fails with an error message saying that it does. I don't know why, it's possible that the error message is a red herring. The key point here is that the same command works in one script, but not the other. BOTH scripts are simply calling `docker --version`.

Comment: And there’s no other `docker` command in your scripts?

Comment: No, I posted the scripts in full. You can copy them and run it yourself to see the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that already, and everything works fine for me.

Comment: How do you run your container?

Comment: `docker run test-image build-developer-database` (my `run.sh` script is located at `/jobs/build-developer-database/run.sh`)

Comment: Jeez - it works now. I ran a docker build with no-cache and it fixed the issue, it was obviously using an old cached version of the scripts. Thanks for your help and apologies for wasting your time mate.